# CGAffineTransformRotate : Detect rotation direction

Tags: ios, objective-c

**What I am trying to do :**

I have an Image of a wheel and a scroll view. User can drag the wheel to rotate it in either direction.
By detecting the direction of rotation. I have to scroll the images placed over scroll view.

**What I am doing is :**

[Following this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/9864/how-to-create-a-rotating-wheel-control-with-uikit)

```
- (BOOL)beginTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    startTouch = touchPoint; // StartTouch is static varialbel
    float dx = touchPoint.x - container.center.x;
    float dy = touchPoint.y - container.center.y;
    deltaAngle = atan2(dy,dx);
    startTransform = container.transform;
    return YES;
}



- (BOOL)continueTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch*)touch withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
 {
    CGPoint pt = [touch locationInView:self];
    float dx = pt.x  - container.center.x;
    float dy = pt.y  - container.center.y;
    float ang = atan2(dy,dx);
    float angleDifference = deltaAngle - ang;
    container.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(startTransform, -angleDifference);
    return YES;
}
```

**Main Problem**

I am not able to detect the Rotation Direction correctly. I am using the **angleDifference** varibale from method **continueTrackingWithTouch** to detect it.

```
if(angleDifference > 0){
// Positive value move in right direction.
}
else{
// Negative value move in left direction.
}
```

This is working ok for small drags of less than 360 dgrees, but after that it's not working properly.
Can anyone suggest me correct approach of Detecting the rotation Direction.

Thanks

Comment: You need to explain, in detail, what your code is and is not doing correctly. What do you mean it doesn't work for rotations greater than 360 degrees. Aren't you rotating by small increments? And is the code that you posted pan gesture recognizer code?

Comment: I am rotating the view with CGAffineTransformRotate by calculating the radians. I am passing angleDifference to rotate it  and alos using it to detect the Direction of rotation. If user rotate the view in anti-clockwise for most of the time it's a positive value and for clockwise it's Negative. But this approach is not working every time.

Comment: "But this approach is not working every time." Ok, what are the situations in which it doesn't work, and what does it do that is wrong?

Comment: I was asuming that a positive value is causing anti-clock movement and negative value is clock-wise.. But it is not the case all time... I am not able to detect in which direction my view is rotating.